# How to eliminate group of observations under conditions

Tags: r, subset

I have a panel data that looks like the following:

```
id  name    year    dummy
1   Jane    1990    1
1   Jane    1991    1
1   Jane    1992    0
1   Jane    1993    0
2   Tom     1978    0
2   Tom     1979    0
2   Tom     1980    0
3   Jim     1981    1
3   Jim     1982    1
3   Jim     1983    0
```

I want to subset this data so that I eliminate people without `1` as `dummy` variable. This means that in the above example, I want to eliminate observations for `Tom`, because he does not have a `dummy` variable of `1`. Wanted output is:

```
id  name    year    dummy
1   Jane    1990    1
1   Jane    1991    1
1   Jane    1992    0
1   Jane    1993    0
3   Jim     1981    1
3   Jim     1982    1
3   Jim     1983    0
```

Would there be a way to code this in R? I'm having trouble because this has to been done by `id`, since I don't want to eliminate ALL observations with `dummy` `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ave` and `subset`:

```
subset(dat, as.logical(ave(dummy, id, FUN = any)))

   id name year dummy
1   1 Jane 1990     1
2   1 Jane 1991     1
3   1 Jane 1992     0
4   1 Jane 1993     0
8   3  Jim 1981     1
9   3  Jim 1982     1
10  3  Jim 1983     0
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: Above is an example, so I get a message In FUN(X[[999L]], ...) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical.

Comment: @Rusuer9000, if you took the time to create a reproducible example, you are more likely to get reproducible solutions. We can't guess at the structure of your data the way you have shared it.

Answer (score 1):

An option using data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(any(dummy)) .SD, by = id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just subset and use `%in%`.

```
df <- df[df$name %in% df$name[df$dummy > 0],]
```

Where df is your data frame

This relies entirely on primitive calls, and so should be (a) pretty fast and (b) not dependent on any packages.

Comment: I would suggest changing from `df$name` to `df$id` since that's what is being used as the ID variable, but +1 for a concise answer that should solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Indeed; brainfart ;).